# Break statement only works for half the login

Tags: python

I am having trouble with one break statement at the end of my code. If I have it there then when the user enters a wrong username and/or password the program will quit and not continue the while loop. If it is not there then after a user logs in successfully, the user is prompted with putting in their username again when it should just exit the program. What should I change to make it all work?

I have tried putting in and taking out break statements and putting in while loops.

```
#login
count = 0
if welcome == "y":
    while True:
        while count < 3:
            use = input("Username:")
            pwd = input("Password:")
            found_username = False
            with open("Credentials.txt", "r") as credentials_file:
                for line in credentials_file:
                    username_login, password_login = line.strip().split(':')

                    if use == username_login:
                        found_username = True
                        if pwd == password_login:
                            print("welcome you are now logged in ")
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Password is incorrect!")
                            count += 1
                            if count == 3:
                                print("Attempts exceeded")
                        break

                if not found_username:
                    print("Username and or password do not exist!")
                    count += 1
                    if count == 3:
                        print("Attempts exceeded")
                else:
                    break

        break
```

\\\\
When the user logs in successfully the program should quit. If they enter in a wrong username and/or password, the user should be prompted with putting in their username and password again until they are correct up to 3 times

Comment: Can you word the question better please (the first part)

Comment: If I have a break statement (not in the code above) above the last break statement in line with the use = input ("Username:"), the program exits when the user enters in the wrong username and/or password, but correctly exits the program when on their first attempt puts in the right username and password.

Comment: Now I am having trouble on when the user enters the correct username but incorrect password, the program should keep looping until the user enters the correct username and password or until they have exceeded all attempts. Currently, the program is just exiting.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement is being executed unconditionally, so you never repeat the loop.

It should only be executed when `found_username` is true, so put it in the `else:` block of the last `if`.

```
            if not found_username:
                print("Username and or password do not exist!")
                count += 1
                if count == 3:
                    print("Attempts exceeded")

            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you've currently constructed the code, you essentially want two loops, 1 that monitors that number of attempts and one that checks for valid credentials. That being said, I highly recommend decoupling the two loops to make it easier for you to reason about the problem. This is why breaking out code is so important - it enables you to spot bugs much more easily.

Additionally, you can leverage a few additional Python concepts. (1) Raising exceptions here to throw specific errors (e.g. username doesn't exist vs. password is incorrect), (2) breaking down the difference between `continue` and `break`. `continue` is for skipping to the next iteration of a loop. `break` is for breaking out of the loop entirely.

For your code, I would recommend something like the following:

```
def authenticate(username, password):
    with open("Credentials.txt", "r") as credentials_file:
        for line in credentials_file:
            username_login, password_login = line.strip().split(':')
            if username_login == username and password_login == password:
                return True  # Everything matches!
            elif username_login == username and password_login != password:
                raise Exception('Password is incorrect!')
            else:
                continue  # Skip to next line in credentials file

    raise Exception('Username does not exist')


if welcome == 'y':
    is_authenticated = False
    for i in range(3):
        username = input('Username:')
        password = input('Password:')

        try:
            authenticate(username, password)
            is_authenticated = True
            break  # Don't need to provide another attempt
        except Exception as e:  
            print(e)  # Print error

    if is_authenticated:
        print('Welcome you are now logged in')
    else:
        print('Attempts exceeded!')
```